# Can I pass axes extents to PairGrid in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to define the axes extents on PairGrids as I plot them. I know I can adjust these after plotting, but I want to map hexbins to the plots, which will be warped if I adjust after the fact. [matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) accepts an extent argument that allows me to define the extents during plotting. I can pass this argument when using a FacetGrid with two variables.

I'd like to provide a list of extents for each variable in a pandas dataframe so I can compare plots across datasets that may not have the same range of values (eg `iris` and `iris_2`).

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
# Create second dataset I'd like to compare, but has different range of values
iris_2 = iris.copy()
iris_2[iris_2.columns[0:4]] = iris_2[iris_2.columns[0:4]] + 2

def hexbin(x, y, **kws):
    cmap = sns.light_palette(kws.pop("color"), as_cmap=True)
    plt.hexbin(x, y, cmap=cmap, mincnt=1, **kws)

g = sns.FacetGrid(iris, col="species")
g = g.map(hexbin, 'sepal_width', 'sepal_length', norm=LogNorm(),
          gridsize=10, extent=[1, 5, 4, 10])
```

[image]
Here's the code I'd like to modify.

```
g = sns.PairGrid(iris, diag_sharey=False)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3, legend=False, shade=True)
g.map_lower(hexbin, gridsize=10, norm=LogNorm())
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, s=3)
```

[image]

When plotting the second dataset, it's not clear how the datasets differ because the axes are adjusted for the individual datasets.

```
g = sns.PairGrid(iris_2, diag_sharey=False)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3, legend=False, shade=True)
g.map_lower(hexbin, gridsize=10, norm=LogNorm())
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, s=3)
```

[image]

In my specific case, and ideal solution might look like a dictionary with desired extents for each dataframe column:

```
extent_dict = {'sepal_length': [4, 10], 'sepal_width': [2, 7],
               'petal_length': [0, 10], 'petal_width': [0, 4.5]}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but wouldn't it be possible to use the `extent`, `g.map(hexbin, 'sepal_width', 'sepal_length', norm=LogNorm(), gridsize=10, extent=<whateveryourextent>)` ?

Comment: I must have been editing the post as you were commenting. That's possible with `FacetGrid`, but not `PairGrid`. As I understand it, passing `extent` for `PairGrid` will apply the same x-y extents for all `hexbin` plots. It's not variable specific.

Comment: In order to be able to compare the different plot you wouldn't want it do be "variable specific", do you?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've clarified the question further. I'd like to be able to compare corresponding plots of the same variables across different datasets, which is easier if they use the same axes extents instead of the automatically chosen extents.